# Selenium in Java Error: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action

Tags: java, selenium, mousehover, invalidargumentexception

I am getting this error "Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action" while trying to execute the below code for Selenium in Java.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_3Ji-EC']/li[8]/a")).click();

    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("_2zrpKA"));
    elem.sendKeys("ABC");

    WebElement elem2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2zrpKA 
    _3v41xv']"));
    elem2.sendKeys("XYZ");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2AkmmA _1LctnI 
    _7UHT_c']")).click();

    System.out.println("Success");

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement elem3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_3Ji-
    EC']/li[7]/a"));
    System.out.println("success");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(elem3).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_1u5ANM']/li[9]/a")).click();
}
```

I have tried this using Selenium 3.4.0 and Firefox 51.x, 52.x, 53.x with the latest geckodriver 16.1 and 16.0 .
When I used Firefox 53.x, I was getting the error "Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string" else every time I am getting the error "Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action".

In the above code I am able to get "success" printed 2nd time without any problem but after that I am getting the error.

Comment: which line gives the error ?

Comment: The last 3 lines. I can see "success" written in the last 4th line printed in my console.

Comment: working fine for me with chrome 58.x chromedriver 2.28 & selenium 3.4.0

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't working in Firefox. It should be I think.

Comment: Can you please let me know your manual step of what are you trying to do through `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_1u5ANM']/li[9]/a")).click();` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your Question:

1. To work with `Selenium 3.4.0` with `geckodriver v0.16.1` & Mozilla Firefox 53.x you need to specify the absolute path of the `geckodriver` in your code as:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
   ```
2. Your xpath seems petty vulnerable to me. You may want to construct more unique logical xpath. To click on `Log In` button you may do:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='AsXM8z']/ul/li/a[@class='_2k0gmP'][text()='Log In']")).click();
   ```
3. I would suggest you not to rely only on class, append some more properties. The xpath for `Enter Email` field can be:

   ```
   WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2zrpKA']"));
   ```
4. The xpath for `Enter Password` is not unique, you may like to change it to:

   ```
    WebElement elem2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv']"));
   ```
5. The xpath for the `Login` button needs to be unique as follows:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2AkmmA _1LctnI _7UHT_c']")).click();
   ```
6. Avoid using `Thread.sleep(5000);` rather use `ImplicitlyWait` or `ExplicitWait`
7. The xpath to click on the Username is again vulnerable, you may like to change it to:

   ```
   WebElement elem3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='AsXM8z']/ul/li/a[@class='_1AHrFc _2k0gmP']"));
   ```
8. The xpath to click the `Log Out` button is again vulnerable, you may like to change it to:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1H5F__']/div/ul/li/ul/li/a[@class='_2k0gmP'][text()='Log Out']")).click();
   ```
9. Here is your own working code block with some simple tweaks;

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='AsXM8z']/ul/li/a[@class='_2k0gmP'][text()='Log In']")).click();

   //Email
   WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2zrpKA']"));
   elem.sendKeys("emailid@domain.com");

   //Password
   WebElement elem2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv']"));
   elem2.sendKeys("pass_word");

   //Login Button
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2AkmmA _1LctnI _7UHT_c']")).click();

   System.out.println("Success");

   //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   Thread.sleep(5000);

   //Click on Name
   WebElement elem3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='AsXM8z']/ul/li/a[@class='_1AHrFc _2k0gmP']"));
   System.out.println("success");
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.moveToElement(elem3).build().perform();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1H5F__']/div/ul/li/ul/li/a[@class='_2k0gmP'][text()='Log Out']")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped and now I am able to execute the code in Firefox as well.

And thanks for the suggestions. I will remember them the next time.

Comment: @RiteshGupta Great news :) Glad that I am able to help.